# Function to convert plotly object to ggplot2?

Tags: ggplot2, plotly

I know the function `ggplotly()` of the `plotly` package converts a `ggplot2` object into a `plotly` one, but is there a function that does the reverse? Converts a `plotly` object to a `ggplot2` one?

Comment: No there is not. It's not possible to cast a `plotly` object to `ggplot2`. and I doubt it will ever be

Comment: That's unfortunate...thank you though!

Answer (score 2):

Boy do I have the solution for you!

We wrote a package to do this. It's called `notly`.

[Notly R package](https://github.com/gdmcdonald/notly)

Installation:

```r
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("gdmcdonald/notly")
```

Example usage:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(notly)

data(iris)

# Create a ggplot
ggplot_object <-
  iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length,
                y = Sepal.Width,
                color = Species))+
      geom_point()

# Create a plotly object - but with the ggplot hiding inside of it as well
notly_obj <-
ggplot_object %>%
  ggplotly

notly_obj

# Extract the ggplot again
ggplot_obj_again <-
  notly_obj %>%
  notly
  
ggplot_obj_again
```

Comment: I appreciate the work here but want to clarify. This package will allow you to go from ggplot -> plotly -> ggplot. 

It will not enable you to got from plotly -> ggplot